# Cassandra order by on partitioned clustering columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am shifting from RDBMS world to NoSQL world and hence have few challenges. My requirement is to create a table as

> Modify the following command to create a new videos_by_tag table partitioned
> based on the tag. The table should also store the rows of each partition so that the
> newest videos are listed first within the partition>.

so I have created the table in the cassandra database as below hope this is correct

```
create table videos_by_tag ( 
tag text, 
video_id timeuuid, 
added_date timestamp, 
Title text, 
PRIMARY KEY ((tag), video_id, added_date )) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (video_id ASC, added_date DESC);
```

and loaded the data.
**Select * from videos_by_tag output is**

```
tag       | video_id                             | added_date                      | title
-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------
  datastax | 4845ed97-14bd-11e5-8a40-8338255b7e33 | 2013-10-16 00:00:00.00000 |              DataStax Studio
  datastax | 5645f8bd-14bd-11e5-af1a-8638355b8e3a | 2013-04-16 00:00:00.00000 | What is DataStax Enterprise?
 cassandra | 1645ea59-14bd-11e5-a993-8138354b7e31 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00.00000 |            Cassandra History
 cassandra | 245e8024-14bd-11e5-9743-8238356b7e32 | 2012-04-03 00:00:00.0000 |             Cassandra & SSDs
 cassandra | 3452f7de-14bd-11e5-855e-8738355b7e3a | 2013-03-17 00:00:00.0000 |              Cassandra Intro
```

My requirements are:

1. Is there a way to sort out the column added_date in DESC, though I specified in the DDL as added_date DESC, I could still see the 2nd row under the tag cassandra's added date is older than the 3rd row.
2. Execute your query again, but list the oldest videos first
3. Change your query to retrieve videos made in 2013 or later

Answer (score 2):

Your primary key has been defined as `((tag), video_id, added_date ))`  with a clustering order of `(video_id ASC, added_date DESC)` - so for each partition (tag), it will order it by the video_id first and then order by the added date.

Since the video_id is unique in the data set above, the order on the date makes little difference since no two records are tied on the video_id to then be sub-ordered on.

If you wanted it order by date within a tag, you would specify the primary key as `((tag), added_date, video_id ))`  with the appropriate clustering `(added_date DESC, video_id ASC)`. You still want `video_id` in there to make sure the primary key remains primary. e.g. unique.

With the appropriate sort order in place, the queries should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I am clear on the sorting by changing the order of clustering columns. My further query is that since I have only 5 rows in the table I can choose the lowest value and pass it on in the > or < operator but in case of large tables how can we know this value?